# How to add a project to subversion using Xcode 7 and change user crendentials

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, repository, xcode7

Earlier import option was available under repository section in organizer but in Xcode7 it's not so. How to add a project to svn?

My svn repository was setup with different user credentials and now when i try to commit with new user credentials,it asks for older user's password with old username disabled for change.
I have also added a new account in xcode preferences, still it is looking for the older username-password.
How can i move ahead with new user credentials?

Answer (score 7):

In order to share **Xcode 5** project on **SVN**, you can do it by doing the following:

**1**. Choose **Xcode** -> **Preferences.**

**2.** Choose **“Accounts”** tab.

**3.** In the **“Accounts”** tab, click **“+”** -> **“Add Repository”.**

**4.** Enter the SVN Repository information.

**P.S.** You may face the following error while trying to add SVN repo to Xcode as follows:
xcode cannot verify the identity of the server

In order to resolve this issue, just click "Show Certificate", unfold the disclosure arrow and set the “Trust” option menu to “Always Trust”.

**5.** After doing these steps, you can choose the local folder ("iOSProjects" for example) in which you want to do svn checkout. You can do this from "Source code" -> "Checkout".

**6.** Finally, you can create (or place) your Xcode project under your local folder "iOSProjects" to add and commit the project files to SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Terminal.**

Right Click on **Project** and **Show in Finder.**

then in **Terminal** Write **cd (drag the folder here).**

Enter.

**svn import - m "Your App Name" Folder Name SVN Url**

Enter

Enter Your credentials.

Done.